# Call Javascript function from codebehind using vb.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I want to call javascript function and pass parameters to it and read the returned value using vb.net .

My Javascript function is

```
  function calcHash(MerchID,OrdNo,Amt,RCode){
    //order no. numerical values only

for (var i=0; i<strlen; i++)
{
        var x = OrdNo.substring(i,i+1)
            if (isNaN(x))
        else strDigit = strDigit + String(x);
}
        OrdNo = strDigit

    //declare variables and assign calculated values
    var HashA = OrdNo * Amt;
    var HashB = MerchID * Amt;
    var HashC = MerchID * OrdNo;
    var TotalHash = String((HashA + HashB + HashC) / (parseInt(MerchID) + parseInt(RCode)));

    //assign only 6 decimal places value
    if (TotalHash.indexOf(".") != -1)
        TotalHash = TotalHash.substr(0,TotalHash.indexOf(".")+7);
    else
        TotalHash = TotalHash + ".000000";

    document.form1.HashCount.value = TotalHash;
}
```

I used this line of code in vb.net (code behind( :

```
   ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.Page, GetType(String), "calcHashFunction", "calcHash();", True)
```

But still i dont know how to pass parameters to this function and how to read the returned value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can assign the returned value to a hidden field in javascript and use it on the server side

```
function calcHash(MerchID, OrdNo, Amt, RCode) 
{
    var TotalHash = String((HashA + HashB + HashC) / (parseInt(MerchID) + parseInt(RCode)));
    var hid=document.getElementById('<hid.ClientID');
    hid.value=TotalHash;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.Page, GetType(String), "calcHashFunction", "var val=calcHash(1,2,3,4);", True)
```

Now you have the returned value in the `val` variable, which you can probably use at the client side.

Use this function:

```
function calcHash(MerchID, OrdNo, Amt, RCode) {
    //order no. numerical values only

    for (var i = 0; i < strlen; i++) {
        var x = OrdNo.substring(i, i + 1)
        if (isNaN(x))
        else strDigit = strDigit + String(x);
    }
    OrdNo = strDigit

    //declare variables and assign calculated values
    var HashA = OrdNo * Amt;
    var HashB = MerchID * Amt;
    var HashC = MerchID * OrdNo;
    var TotalHash = String((HashA + HashB + HashC) / (parseInt(MerchID) + parseInt(RCode)));

    //assign only 6 decimal places value
    if (TotalHash.indexOf(".") != -1) TotalHash = TotalHash.substr(0, TotalHash.indexOf(".") + 7);
    else TotalHash = TotalHash + ".000000";

    document.form1.HashCount.value = TotalHash;
    return TotalHash;
}
```

So, in your `val` variable, you'll have your `TotalHash`.

You can also use it like this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.Page, GetType(String), "calcHashFunction", "var val=calcHash(" + Merchantid + "," + OrderNo + "," + Amount + "," + ReturnCode + ");", True)
```

Comment: How to make my javascript function return the TotalHash ?

Comment: WHat is the value that you want to return from your function?

Comment: How to assign values to the function using code behind ? suppose I have variables and want to pass it into the function to return the value

Comment: The value that I want to return from the function is TotalHash

Comment: How to insert my own variables from code behind in this statement var val=calcHash(1,2,3,4); instead of 1 i want to put MerchID variable

Comment: Just concatenate them and use

Comment: you mean like this : ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.Page, GetType(String), "calcHashFunction", "var val=calcHash(" & Merchantid & "," & OrderNo & "," & Amount & "," & ReturnCode & ");", True)